# Outlook VBA ThisOutlookSession 2 macros possible?

Tags: vba, outlook, event-handling

I have 2 macros that I would like to use in outlook.  The first announces appointments.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
 
If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then
  Exit Sub
End If
 
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim timeOffset As Long
Dim strTimeOffset As String
Set xlApp = Excel.Application

timeOffset = (Item.Start - Now) * 1440

Select Case True
Case timeOffset < 60 'starts in under 1 hour
  strTimeOffset = timeOffset & " minutes, "

Case timeOffset <= 1440 'starts in under a day
  timeOffset = timeOffset / 60 
  strTimeOffset = timeOffset & " hours, "
  
Case timeOffset > 1440 'starts in more than a day
  timeOffset = timeOffset / 1440
  strTimeOffset = timeOffset & " days, on " & Format(Item.Start, "mmmm d")
End Select

 xlApp.Speech.Speak Item.Subject & "Starts in " & strTimeOffset & " at " & Format(Item.Start, "hh:mm am/pm"), True

Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The second sends a scheduled email.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objMsg As MailItem
Dim objApp As AppointmentItem
Dim Att As Attachment
Dim tmpFolder As String
Dim filePath As String
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
MsgBox "Appointment Triggered"
'message is appointment
If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then Exit Sub
'The appointment is set as "Send Schedule Recurring Email" Category
If Item.Categories <> "Send Schedule Recurring Email" Then Exit Sub
'MsgBox Item.MessageClass
'MsgBox Item.Categories
'MsgBox Item.Location
'MsgBox Item.Subject
'MsgBox objMsg.Body
'MsgBox Environ("USERPROFILE")
'to get the path of the email attachment
tmpFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE")
'Add each attachment to email object to be sent
For Each Att In Item.Attachments
filePath = tmpFolder & "\" & Att.FileName
Att.SaveAsFile (filePath)
objMsg.Attachments.Add filePath
Kill filePath
Next Att
'send email object
objMsg.To = Item.Location
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Body = Item.Body
objMsg.Send
Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Each works individually but I would like to use both.  I am unfortunately not much of a programmer so I was hoping someone could shed some light if it would be possible to combine these or create a second instance of ThisOutlookSession so I can use both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Item to each of your (renamed) subs:

```vb
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    SaySomething Item
    SendAMail Item
End sub

Sub SaySomething(ByVal Item As Object)
   'do the speaking thing with `Item`
End sub

Sub SendAMail(ByVal Item As Object)
   'do the mail thing with `Item`
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the code from different sources in a single sub or just split it into separate functions like Tim has shown. I think the latter is better:

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  AnnounceAppointments Item
  SendScheduledEmail Item
End Sub

Private Sub AnnounceAppointments(ByVal Item as Object)
  If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then
    Exit Sub
  End If
 
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
  Dim timeOffset As Long
  Dim strTimeOffset As String
  Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

  timeOffset = (Item.Start - Now) * 1440

  Select Case True
  Case timeOffset < 60 'starts in under 1 hour
    strTimeOffset = timeOffset & " minutes, "

  Case timeOffset <= 1440 'starts in under a day
    timeOffset = timeOffset / 60 
    strTimeOffset = timeOffset & " hours, "
  
  Case timeOffset > 1440 'starts in more than a day
    timeOffset = timeOffset / 1440
    strTimeOffset = timeOffset & " days, on " & Format(Item.Start, "mmmm d")
  End Select

  xlApp.Speech.Speak Item.Subject & "Starts in " & strTimeOffset & " at " & Format(Item.Start, "hh:mm am/pm"), True

  Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub SendScheduledEmail(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim objMsg As MailItem
  Dim objApp As AppointmentItem
  Dim Att As Attachment
  Dim tmpFolder As String
  Dim filePath As String
  Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  MsgBox "Appointment Triggered"
  'message is appointment
  If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then Exit Sub
  'The appointment is set as "Send Schedule Recurring Email" Category

  If Item.Categories <> "Send Schedule Recurring Email" Then Exit Sub
  'MsgBox Item.MessageClass
  'MsgBox Item.Categories
  'MsgBox Item.Location
  'MsgBox Item.Subject
  'MsgBox objMsg.Body
  'MsgBox Environ("USERPROFILE")
  'to get the path of the email attachment
  tmpFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE")
  'Add each attachment to email object to be sent
  For Each Att In Item.Attachments
    filePath = tmpFolder & "\" & Att.FileName
    Att.SaveAsFile (filePath)
    objMsg.Attachments.Add filePath
    Kill filePath
  Next Att
  'send email object
  objMsg.To = Item.Location
  objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
  objMsg.Body = Item.Body
  objMsg.Send
  Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```